# AES256 Encryption in C#

Tags: c#, aes

I am using `System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged` class in C#(.NET 3.5) to do encryption with settings:

```
RijndaelManaged AesCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();
AesCrypto.BlockSize = 128;
AesCrypto.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
CryptoStream CryptStream = new CryptoStream(memStream1,
    AesCrypto.CreateEncryptor(EncryptionKey1, EncryptionIV1),
                    CryptoStreamMode.Write);
```

And with 256 bit key and IV. I believe that results in AES256. Am I right?

Would there be any differences if I am using `System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged` class?

Also, I was thinking, we TRUST Microsoft implementation of AES, can this be verified, or maybe one should write his own implementation of AES?

Comment: If you're paranoid then write your own implementation. If you really want to verify the code of Microsoft, then simply decompile the class and check it yourself. Both things are a waste of time.

Comment: Never write your own implementation. Microsoft's implementation has been tested a lot more than your implementation ever will be. Do you want to take the risk of having a bunch of encrypted data that's not decryptable anymore?

Comment: check the MS implementation's output against the output of any other implementation of AES ... what do you expect to find in the MS implementation, if the output is identical to any other implementation's output?

Comment: I was looking for something like this: Open source encryption library: http://www.bouncycastle.org/index.html

Answer (score 1):

About the differences between `AesManaged` and `RijndaelManaged`:

> The AES algorithm is essentially the Rijndael symmetric algorithm with a fixed block size and iteration count. This class functions the same way as the RijndaelManaged class but limits blocks to 128 bits and does not allow feedback modes.

Taken from MSDN, here is the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx

Comment: Right guy, I saw that before. Can you tell me from that article what “iteration count.” means, and what crypto mode of operation is that?

Comment: The Password-Based Key Derivation Function takes the bit string and salt value, and repeatedly applies a pseudo-random function, such as a hash function, to produce the cryptographic key.

The number of applications of the hash function is called the iteration count. Both the salt and the iteration count have been introduced to thwart exhaustive attacks.